# Chemical structure of xenon heptafluoride anion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, hybridization, lewis-structure

When $\ce{XeF6}$ acts as a fluoride acceptor, $\ce{XeF7-}$ is formed. What is the hybridisation, geometry, and shape of $\ce{XeF7-}$?

Comment: Congratulations on your Yearling Badge!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the geometry and shape:

[image]

Source: *Housecroft, Sharpe, Inorganic Chemistry, Pearson Education Limited, 2005*

Comment: As we know that XeF6 has a lone pair of electron then what happens to that lone pair of electron when XeF6 reacts with F-?